# Grub: install only the MBR parts, not the boot directory?

Tags: boot, grub2, mbr

It seems as though I always have to install files to a `--boot-directory` when using `grub-install`.

What if I already have existing grub files in `/boot` on my partitions? Shouldn't I just need to install the MBR parts of grub and point it to one of my existing partitions' `/boot/grub`? I was unable to find such an option.

I've downgraded my GPT to MBR and removed my BIOS boot partition, which means I need to reinstall Grub to my MBR, if I haven't misunderstood anything. Without doing that I'm left with a grub rescue prompt that can't even list my partitions when doing `ls`. I realise that my menu entries might still not work after reinstalling grub to the MBR since they refer to partitions like `hd0,gpt5`, but having a usable prompt would be good enough, and it would have allowed me to confirm my understanding of grub more easily.

Do I have to write to a `--boot-directory` whenever I want to install grub, even if a directory already exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When GRUB boots from a MBR, the number of legacy BIOS compatibility steps it needs to take at the beginning of the boot process means that the code actually in the MBR is only capable of loading **one disk block** whose LBA number is patched in to the MBR code at the time of installation. That block is usually the first block of *GRUB core image*. It contains the code to load more blocks, and a list of block numbers that defines where the rest of the GRUB core image is located.

On a MBR-partitioned disk, there is usually unused space between the MBR and the start of the first partition. With MS-DOS, the original convention was to start the first partition at the start of the next disk track, which usually means there will be at least 63 disk blocks before the first partition, including the MBR. On modern systems, the first MBR partition is now more commonly placed to start at exactly 1MiB from the beginning of the disk, i.e. at block #2048, to optimize the data alignment for disks, SSDs and SAN storage systems that may internally use a block size bigger than 512 bytes.

So, on a MBR-partitioned disk, the beginning of the disk is normally arranged like this:

- block #0: MBR
- block #1: first block of GRUB core image, contains the block list
- blocks #2...#n: the rest of the GRUB core image
- block #2048: beginning of the first partition.

Note that the loading of the GRUB core image works exclusively by pre-determined block numbers: until the GRUB core image is fully loaded and extracted, GRUB will have no awareness of partition tables nor filesystems of any kind.

On a GPT-partitioned disk, the blocks immediately after block #0 are occupied by the GPT partition table, so the GRUB core image is embedded into a "BIOS boot partition" instead. That just means the block number embedded into the MBR will not be 1, but instead the number of the first block of the BIOS boot partition, and the rest of the blocks belonging to the core image will be likewise shifted. So on a GPT-partitioned disk with BIOS-style GRUB on it, the physical layout will be something like this, assuming the BIOS boot partition is the first one on the disk:

- block #0: GPT protective MBR, with GRUB MBR code embedded
- blocks #1...#(x-1): actual GPT partition table
- block #x: the first block of the BIOS boot partition, contains first block of GRUB core image with the block list
- blocks #(x+1)...#(x+n): the rest of the GRUB core image

The fact that you can still get to GRUB rescue mode indicates that although you said you removed your BIOS boot partition, you did not yet **overwrite** its blocks; although the space occupied by the BIOS boot partition may now be unallocated space between partitions, or unused space in another resized partition, it still has its old contents, and GRUB can still load those blocks and find its core image. But nothing in particular shields those blocks now from getting overwritten: as soon as that happens for whatever reason, the GRUB core image will be destroyed and GRUB will fail to get even as far as the rescue mode.

### Contents of the GRUB core image

The GRUB core image contains several things:

- the GRUB kernel: this is the only part technically required to get into GRUB rescue mode.
- embedded initial GRUB root path, to indicate which disk, partition and directory within it holds the GRUB configuration file and the GRUB modules directory. In Linux, these normally appear as `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and `/boot/grub/i386-pc` respectively when the Linux system is running normally.
- a set of embedded GRUB modules, containing at least the code to read and understand the partition table and the filesystem type used on the partition referred to by the initial GRUB root path. As the core image may need to fit into less than 63 disk blocks, this set of modules is usually kept as minimal as possible on MBR systems.
- optionally, an *embedded GRUB configuration file* with one or more GRUB commands
- optionally, an embedded disk image, similar to the ones used by the `memdisk` tool of the SYSLINUX bootloader family
- optionally, a GPG public key used to sign other GRUB modules and the OS kernel for security (and to satisfy Secure Boot acceptance requirements on UEFI versions of GRUB)

All this is LZMA compressed to minimize its size, so it cannot be easily read or modified manually.

Since you're now dropping into rescue mode and cannot list your partitions, that indicates the GRUB core image contains the partitioning module for GPT (`part_gpt.mod`), but not for MBR (`part_msdos.mod`). Without the MBR partitioning module, it cannot access the partition containing `/boot/grub/i386-pc` directory, even if the GRUB core image would contain the filesystem driver module applicable to it... and so GRUB cannot load the `normal.mod` which would let you proceed beyond the rescue mode.

### What needs to happen now

- The GRUB core image may need to be rewritten to a safe location, probably into the space between the MBR and the beginning of the first partition, which was previously occupied by the structures of the GPT partition table. As the BIOS boot partition was removed, the current location is not safe: it might be reallocated to another partition and get overwritten without warning in the future.
- while rewriting the GRUB core image, the GPT partitioning module embedded within it needs to be replaced with the MBR partitioning module. Since all the components are supposed to be at hand in uncompressed form (at `/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc` or similar directory), the simplest way to do it is just take all the appropriate uncompressed components, build a new core image out of them and compress it. Uncompressing the old one and modifying it is just not worth the trouble: why write another piece of code when reusing the code used when initially installing GRUB from scratch works just fine?
- Since the location of the GRUB core image will most likely change, the MBR code needs to be rewritten too.
- The `grub-install` command will need to somehow ensure that the `normal.mod` and other GRUB modules located in `/boot/grub/i386-pc` are of the same version as the new GRUB core image. Sure, it could compare the existing files to the set of files it used to rebuild the core image, but again... why write and debug code for another special case when simply overwriting the existing contents of `/boot/grub/i386-pc` with the already-existing GRUB installation routine works just fine?

The total uncompressed size of all the `i386-pc` GRUB components is definitely less than 4 MiB. That's nothing. Trying to avoid rewriting that if it already exists is simply not worth the trouble, unless you're working with something special like the old first-generation PATA SSDs with very restricted number of write cycles available.

### How native UEFI would do it?

Since UEFI firmware includes FAT32 filesystem support as standard, the native UEFI version of the GRUB bootloader can be packaged as a single `grubx64.efi` file that contains all the necessary modules, *including* `normal.mod` if you wish. It gets loaded as a regular file: no need to fiddle with block numbers or embedded code in fixed disk locations at all.

Comment: This was a very good read. You identified almost every question I didn't ask, answered everything I didn't know and confirmed the rest. I especially appreciated the list of what the core image contained. From that it is very clear that my GRUB is still reading from unallocated disk space. If I understood correctly, `--boot-directory` also determines what the embedded initial GRUB root path will be. It wasn't apparent in my question, but I had sort of assumed that installing to `/boot` would overwrite configuration files, which I now realise was probably wrong. 10/10

Comment: The only configuration files under `/boot` would be `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` which gets completely regenerated based on `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/grub.d/*` each time you run `grub[2]-mkconfig` (or `update-grub` in Debian-related systems), `/boot/grub/device.map` which is only needed in some special cases, and possibly `/boot/grub/grubenv` which stores the most recent choice made in GRUB boot menu and is only used if `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` is used in `/etc/default/grub`. All of these should be fairly easy to reconstruct if necessary, and `grub-install` may even reconstruct some of them.