# I have an issue while recovery of grub

Tags: linux, grub2, rescue

Iam using RHEL 7.6 , i just change the " grub2 " directory name

and rebooted the system .

After that  i saw the screen like this
[image]

[image]

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: "_i just change the ' grub2 ' directory name_" is unclear. What is the full original path, and what is the full new path? And what is your RHEL boot/root partition? The first partition of the first disk?

Comment: If you don't get the system up again with telcoM's answer, I recommend booting a life system and change the name back.

Answer (score 1):

Your old `prefix` setting was `prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/grub2`. This tells me you have a separate `/boot` filesystem on partition `(hd0,msdos1)` because the old prefix does not mention `/boot` and *it used to work* until you made your change.

Note that GRUB accesses only one filesystem at a time: it does not know nor care that `(hd0,msdos1)` is normally mounted under `/boot` in Linux. It only needs the part of the pathname that is actually part of that filesystem, as GRUB effectively treats the `/boot` as the root directory for its own needs. That's what the variable `root=hd0,msdos1` means. And that is also why the old prefix has the pathname as just `/grub2`, not as `/boot/grub2`.

By specifying the new prefix as `(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub2`, you effectively told GRUB to look at what would be `/boot/boot/grub2` in Linux.

If you did something like `mv /boot/grub2 /boot/newname`, you must now use `set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/newname` to make the prefix reflect the new name of the `grub2` directory.

If you moved the `grub2` directory out of the `/boot` filesystem, you have a bigger problem, as GRUB only has the minimum modules installed in its core image to access the `grub2` directory: if the new location is on a LVM volume or has a different filesystem type than your `/boot` filesystem, it is quite likely that GRUB won't be able to read it. If this is what you did, you'll need to boot into rescue mode from the RHEL 7.6 installation media, and then use `grub-install` to reinstall GRUB to fully adapt it to the new location: it will first choose the required modules and run `grub-mkimage` to create a new GRUB core image file with the correct modules, then embed it to the MBR and the disk blocks between the MBR and the beginning of the first partition.

For more background information on the structure of GRUB, please see [this earlier answer I wrote about GRUB](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/542184/258991).